# How to remove space (?) from empty line using perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to remove the empty lines from [this file](http://pastebin.com/PCjDVh2p) so that there are only two `\n` between stanzas of the song. There appear to be spaces on lines 7, 8, and 20, but I'm guessing they aren't regular spaces because I haven't been able to remove them with substitutions that use `\s`.

The text is reproduced below (with the spaces marked by `<-- HERE` for clarity), but the Stack Overflow editor seems to have changed the special spaces into regular ones, so you'll have to look at the original file to duplicate my problem.

```
9a I Believe in a Hill Called Mount Calvary

1 There are things, as we travel this earth's shifting sands,
That transcend all the reason
But the things that matter the most in this world,
They can never be held in our hand
 <-- HERE
 <-- HERE

Chorus
I believe in a hill called mount Calvary,
I believe whatever the cost!
And when time has surrendered and earth is no more
I'll still cling to that old rugged cross

2 I believe that the Christ who was slain on the cross,
Has the power to change lives today;
For He changed me completely a new life is mine
That is why by the cross I will stay
 <-- HERE

3 I believe that this life, with its great mysteries,
Surely someday will come to an end;
But faith will conquer the darkness and death
And will lead me at last to my Friend
```

I tried `perl -pe 's/\n{3,}/\n\n/g'` which didn't work as there was some space in the lines 7, 8 and 20.

I can't remove the space, no matter what I try. I tried the following commands:

1. `perl -p0e 's/\s{3,}/\n\n/g'`
2. `perl -pe 's/^\s$//g'`
3. `perl -pe 's/^ $//g'`
4. `perl -pe 's/ $//g'`

None of these work. I want to know why this is happening. Could there be a `non-space` character that acts as a blank?

What should I do to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to Jens' suggestion to use `od -bc filename`.

The dump showed characters `302 240` in the place of the space in the lines 7, 8 and 20.

On searching for the details on the octal values, I got the following from [here](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/hidden-characters-in-source-code-causing-compiler-grief.679103/):

> man iso_8859-1 identifies \240 as NO-BREAK SPACE
>   and \302 as LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX

I found how to remove the characters from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697017/how-to-remove-non-ascii-characters-and-append-a-space-in-the-field-where-the-non).

I used to command `perl -pi -e 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' filename` to correct this.

Thank you for all the tips given and effort put forth.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do to get rid of this?

If you suspect funny characters, look at the file with `od -bc filename` and look for unusual characters.

I have used your file, after removing the `<-- HERE` marks, and your first alternative `perl -p0e 's/\s{3,}/\n\n/g' file` works just fine. This is a strong indication (aka proof :-) that something like this is the cause.

Comment: Yep, they're no-break spaces. The OP originally had a pastebin link to their file; I edited it out and copied the contents here, but apparently the Stack Overflow editor strips no-break spaces. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing tip. The lines 7, 8 and 20 displays values `302 240 012` on the line above and values `302 240 \n` on the line below.

Comment: I found that these were non-ascii characters introduced by the Powerpoint processor from which I extracted this song. I found the solution through the post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697017/how-to-remove-non-ascii-characters-and-append-a-space-in-the-field-where-the-non)

Answer (score 1):

As I observed, the `spaces` are just non-printable characters. Suggest you try the following:

```
perl -p0e 's/(?:[\x80-\xFF][\x0D\x0A]{2})+//g'
```

Comment: This does not work. On using `od -bc filename` The lines 7, 8 and 20 displays values `302 240 012` on the line above and values `302 240 \n` on the line below.

Comment: So where to download a copy of the original file? Not just copy/paste from the given link.

Comment: Did  you try the pastebin link given in the question? I copy pasted the file into the pastebin

Comment: I did, and the pattern did not work on your side. I just wanted to know the Hex values of those so-called  `spaces`.

Comment: Sorry I had already modified the files to reflect what I wanted

Comment: It's nice to know you got the question resolved. I downloaded the file `PCjDVh2p.txt` from the link, and came up with the above pattern.

Answer (score -1):

I think the following solution can solve your problem

```
open FH,"/home/httpd/cgi-bin/space.txt";
while(<FH>)
{
print if (!/^\s*$/) ;
}
```